# Does parameter packs carry a set limit?

Tags: c++, c++17, parameter-pack

Is there any upper limit to, or maximum number of elements of [Parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) like there is for maximum template recursion depth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that a  separate limit is necessary. The number of elements is dictated by the site of instantiation and how many template arguments can be passed to a template:

- There is a limit of the [number of arguments to a function call](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.12) (recommended minimum: 256).
- There is a limit of the [number of template parameters](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.40) in a template declaration (recommended minimum: 1024)

The first is definitively applicable, and the second may apply if the implementation has to expand a pack into a full declaration internally. (But I do not know for sure; I do not write C++ compilers.)